# How to create a Custom Split Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-object, activities, journeybuilder

I would like to know where I can find any documentation about how to configure the "config.json" file in order to create a Custom Split Activity as shown [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/#SplitActivities).

I have also found [information](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/platform/creating-platform-activities.html) saying that I should not use "Flow Control" "Custom Activities" but seems pretty old. Is this information still valid?

And one more question, can I create Custom Activities with more than 2 outputs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've documented the properties used in the config.json in [**this table**](https://github.com/eliotharper/journey-builder-dev-guide/blob/master/tmp/config-json-properties.md) with property names expressed in dot notation where appropriate. (it turns out that StackExchange does not support Markdown tables so I've had to push this to my repo).

Regarding your question on setting the Activity category in App Center, you can choose from:

- Data Updates
- Flow Control
- Messaging

If you don't assign a category in App Center, the Custom Activity will be listed under a 'Custom' heading in the Activities list within the Interaction Canvas.

The structure of a config.json file is provided below.

```
{
   "workflowApiVersion":"1.0",
   "metaData":{
      "version":"2.0",
      "icon":"images/activity-icon.png",
      "iconSmall":"images/activity-icon-small.png"
   },
   "type":"REST",
   "outcomes":[
      {
         "arguments":{
            "branchResult":"wishlist_item",
            "argument":"passed from config.json for wishlist_item"
         }
      },
      {
         "arguments":{
            "branchResult":"cart_item",
            "argument":"passed from config.json for cart_item"
         }
      },
      {
         "arguments":{
            "branchResult":"purchase_item",
            "argument":"passed from config.json for purchase_item"
         },
         "metaData":{
         "label":"Purchase"
   }
      }
   ],
   "lang":{
      "en-US":{
         "name":"Custom Split",
         "description":"A Custom Split Activity with multiple outcomes",
         "i18n_wishlist":"Wishlist",
         "i18n_cart":"Cart",
         "i18n_purchase":"Purchase"
      }
   },
   "outcomeLabelLanguageMap":{
      "wishlist_item":"i18n_wishlist",
      "cart_item":"i18n_cart",
      "purchase_item":"i18n_purchase"
   },
   "userInterfaces":{
      "runningModal":{
         "url":"runningModal.html"
      },
      "runningHover":{
         "url":"runningHover.html"
      }
   },
   "arguments":{
      "execute":{
         "inArguments":[
            { "firstName":"{{Contact.Attribute.Customers.FirstName}}" },
            { "lastName":"{{Contact.Attribute.Customers.LastName}}" },
            { "emailAddress":"{{Contact.Default.Email}}" }
         ],
         "outArguments":[
            { "caseID":"number" }
         ],
         "url":"https://domain.com/activity-path/execute/",
         "verb":"POST",
         "body":"",
         "header":"",
         "format":"json",
         "useJwt":false,
         "timeout":10000
      }
   },
   "configurationArguments":{
      "applicationExtensionKey":"extension-key-created-in-app-center",
      "defaults":{ "name":"value" },
      "save":{
         "url":"https://domain.com/activity-path/save/",
         "body":"",
         "verb":"POST",
         "useJwt":false
      },
      "publish":{
         "url":"https://domain.com/activity-path/publish/",
         "verb":"POST",
         "body":"",
         "useJwt":false
      },
      "validate":{
         "url":"https://domain.com/activity-path/validate/",
         "verb":"POST",
         "body":"",
         "useJwt":false
      }
   },
   "edit":{
      "url":"https://domain.com/activity-path/",
      "height":400,
      "width":500
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some imformation about what kind I have to response from the Custom Split Decision API in order to select one outcome or another?

Comment: Hello Jose, the Custom Split Activity documenation is [provided here](https://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/platform/extending-platform-activities.html). In summary, you will need to include an `outcomes` object in your config.json file. Each default outcome must contain a `branchResult` field. Journey Builder will expect the response of the custom activity's Execute REST call to contain an object `{ branchResult: <value> }`, where `<value>` matches the `branchResult` of one of the Activity's outcomes.